# Cultivation Isekai where main character takes any student that will come

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai, cultivation

I do not remember much sorry.

Main character starts by taking random students anyone who will join him and he takes some old guy and makes him into cultivator(which was thought impossible) the old man turns out to be some big government official this is a small part of the story.

Main point is he’s a teacher and the more students he gets the more powerful he gets and the more powerful the students get he eventually has to fight in a competition and the old man fights and wins then I blank.

The problem is there’s so many stories like this so I don’t know which one.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?

Comment: Mangaread or manganato sorry about the lack of information

Answer (score 1):

**Best Teacher Baek**
[image]
Once the finest instructor in the Blood Cult, Suryong Baek is killed, only to to wake up in the body of someone who teaches martial arts at a small rural academy. His new body may be weak, but he knows how to fix it, and it’s not the first time that he’s found himself in a body that can’t access its inner power. Curing his body requires money, however, and Suryong decides that becoming the greatest instructor at a top academy is the best way to do it. Since he’ll be up against tough competition, Suryong will have to use everything he’s got to become a teaching superstar.

Comment: I don't remember him getting stronger because of his disciples, but the story about him taking an old man is present and goes exactly per requester's description